# Open connection to remote MySQL using non default (unix) socket

Tags: mysql, .net, sockets, powershell

I'm in a situation where I have to push data to a remote database, from a Powershell script.

The database's server uses multiple instances, each one using a specific socket.

I'm trying to open a connection remotely, using the .Net MySQL connector as follow :

```
$mdir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$mdir\MySQL.Data.dll")        
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "host=$myHost;port=$Port;uid=$User;pwd=$Pass;database=$Database;Socket=$Socket;Pooling=False"
$connection.Open()
```

I'm getting an error saying that Socket is not an existing keyword.
I've found reference to that keyword on google, but indeed not in the official documentation.

Example showing what I want to connect to :

```
Server : db.domain.com 
Port : 2345 
Socket : /var/sockets/mycustomsocket.sock
```

Is there a way to do what I want, and if so, what am I doing wrong ?

#### EDIT

What I was doing wrong is putting too much trust into the technical knowledge of my client, but at least, I learned something !

The case I described is pure nonsense due to the way MySQL works.
When an instance uses a socket, that socket is bound to a specific port. The case that my client described to me that lead to that question is therefore impossible.

It is not possible to have several instances of MySQL listening on the same port, but using different sockets. Wanting to connect to a remote file socket is therefore a non issue, and you should be able to connect using ip/hostname and port.

The Socket parameter in MySQL is supposed to be used locally, as it was noted in the comments.

Comment: Are you confusing `socket` for `port`? If the keyword doesn't exist, how do you expect to use it?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. The question is how to connect to that configuration, the Socket keyword seems to exist in the ODBC driver and some documentation, but I can't find it in the .Net documentation.

Comment: [This](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/specifying-socket/) shows that the `socket` keyword is only used for local connections. Do you have multiple instances listening to the same port but different sockets?

Comment: Well, after reading your question, I went to look at how sockets worked in MySQL and I guess that I shouldn't have listened to my client. Seems like a socket on a server running MySQL is bound to a port and the case where multiple instances uses one port and several sockets is therefore impossible.